# Determining the image compression algorithm used on TIFF images

Tags: images

I several **TIFF** images in a folder. How can I determine which image compression algorithm they use?

When I do `file` I get

```
100 (2).tif:                 TIFF image data, little-endian
100.tif:                     TIFF image data, little-endian
```

These results don't say which algorithm is used, or even whether it's lossy or lossless. How can I figure this out? Solutions can be Windows- or Linux-based.

Comment: Looking at the image's extension should be enough.

Comment: isn't the extension a sufficient information? else, `file` gives you the basic infos on a file (linux/macosx)

Comment: Most compression algorithms include a header with a fixed tag of some form. It wouldn't be too much of a challenge to roll your own identifier.

Comment: Icarus, you are supposing that tiff-files only use one compression algorithm. That is wrong. You have options like uncompressed, pack bits, lzw, zip and others.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [W_Whalley](https://superuser.com/a/402912/167207)'s `identify -verbose` suggestion instead. If you're in a linux/cygwin environment, pipe it to `grep -i compression` and you'll have your one-line answer. I.e.

```
identify -verbose /path/to/your/file.tiff | grep -i compression
```

Comment: That gives me “Zip” even though I've told GIMP to use Deflate. GIMP doesn't list "Zip" as an option. Any ideas of why it returns that?

Answer (score 4):

If you have ImageMagick installed, use the display tool to show the image.

Right-click on the image and choose Image Info, then look for the Compression: setting (it's near the bottom of the list).

Or if you want the minimum information use the `identify` tool with the `-verbose` switch, then filter the result to look for the “Compression” line.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but the question was probably about finding out *in an automated way* (e.g. by using a command-line tool).

Answer (score 2):

What about the `file` command? Example:

```
$ file /usr/share/apache2/icons/a.png
/usr/share/apache2/icons/a.png: PNG image, 20 x 22, 4-bit colormap, non-interlaced
```

Comment: But where is the name of the algorithm used ?

Comment: PNG is a compression algorithm (a lossless one). Image file formats are typically named after thier compression algorithm. The term "JPEG" for example, doesn't technically refer to a file type; it refers to a compression scheme. Colloquially the two are pretty universally conflated, but the type of image (TIFF, PNG, etc.) usually (but not always) refers to the compression algorithm used.

Comment: TIFF can be made to work with both lossless and lossy compression. This is my real problem. I need to determine which of them uses lossy and which uses lossless and the name of the algorithm

Comment: Sorry, TIFF was a bad example. The TIFF format usually uses LZW, but there are (rare, but present) implementations of it that use other algorithms as well.

Comment: @ZacB actually TIFF format is also there in the folder that iam inspecting.

Comment: Use W_Whalley's `identify -verbose` suggestion instead. If you're in a linux/cygwin environment, pipe it to `grep compression` and you'll have your one-line answer.

Comment: hi @Zac B could you answer my question with your suggestion. You saved me here because i really wanted a command line tool to do this, and i like to award you points for that.

Comment: Actually, `file` worked perfectly fine for me: `TIFF image data, little-endian, direntries=26, height=5255, bps=326, compression=LZW, PhotometricIntepretation=RGB, description=                               , manufacturer=SONY, model=DSC-RX100, orientation=upper-left, width=15814`! However, there are many different versions of `file`.

Answer (score 1):

`identify` works, but it's slow for big files.

```
identify -verbose
```

One may use `tiffinfo` instead.

```
tiffinfo test.tif | grep Compression
```

Use this command for installation (on Ubuntu):

```
apt-get install libtiff-tools
```

Comment: `identify` outputs merely `TIFF64 1065x532 1065x532+0+0 8-bit sRGB 102592B 0.000u 0:00.000` on a Deflate-compressed TIFF, and `tiffinfo` isn't available for `cpe:/o:opensuse:tumbleweed:20240216`... :<