# How to batch-convert JPG files to uncompressed TIFF

Tags: images, jpeg, imagemagick, tiff, image-conversion

I need to collect 1000 uncompressed TIFF files. I have a large set of JPG images, so I decided to convert them to TIFF format. The loss in quality is ok in this case for me.

I used the following command to convert a folder of JPG images to TIFF:

```
mogrify -format tiff *.jpg -compress none
```

Even though I included `-compress none`, it somehow uses JPEG compression. How can I convert JPEG files to uncompressed TIFF files then?

Comment: How have you determined that the resultant tiff file uses jpg compression?

Comment: using imagemagick identify tool

Comment: can you provide the dump?

Comment: i ask it for a question and here it is http://superuser.com/questions/402829/determining-the-image-compression-algorithm-used-on-tiff-images

Comment: sorry, i meant can you provide some information that specifically says that it is a tiff file with jpeg compression after it is converted? Your link provides no ouput from a tool etc which would indicate what the compression method is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use imagemagick? and say

```
convert -compress none *.jpg Picts.tiff
```

Tell me if it works right for you

Comment: Yes, use `convert` instead of `mogrify`

Answer (score 4):

Once an image is converted or created in jpg format, the detail is lost.

The "compression" in jpg is not like a zip file in which the file is made smaller but every bit still exists. Jpg uses [lossy compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) -- this means that some data is lost during the compression process.

The best you'll be able to do is to have a tiff file with the same quality as your (compressed, lossy) jpg.

To do better, you'd have to recapture the original in a non-lossy format.

Comment: actually my problem is i need a collection of 1000 files in tiff format, and there is no other method of obtaining them other than converting jpg's to tiff. Therefore converting jpg to tiff is ok for my purpose.

Comment: TIFF supports lzw, zip, and jpg compression within the format via extensions. jpg compression handling is rare in tools, but Photoshop (for instance) supports its use.

Comment: well tiff is able to store uncompressed format as well

Answer (score 0):

Try `-compress None` as options once you have originals (as noted by @DougHarris).

Comment: Iam not interested in the end quality of the converted images. I only need a collection of tiff files. Thats all